# $S_4$ is not nilpotent but has central lower central series.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, noncommutative-algebra

The lower central series of $S_4$ is given by :
$$\gamma_1 =S_4\ge \gamma_2=A_4\ge\gamma_3=A_4\ge \gamma_4 =A_4\ge...  $$

This series is clearly central as each $\gamma_i/\gamma_{i+1}$ is central in $S_4/\gamma_{i+1}$ but $S_4$ is known to be not nilpotent. While we know that a lower central series of a group $G$ is central if and only if the group $G$ is nilpotent, which means that the series starts at $G$ and terminates at $\{1\}$  at some finite step.
Is there anything I'm missing in this reasoning. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You got the definition slightly wrong: nilpotent iff the lower central series ends at $\{1\}$.

Comment: that's what I said,nilpotent if the lower central series ends  at $\{1\}$

Comment: @palio: A finite group is nilpotent iff every maximal subgroup is normal. Since $S_4$ has not-normal maximal subgroups (consider its $2$-Sylow-subgroups), it is not nilpotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if the lower central series ends at $1$, if and only if the upper central series ands at $G$.
Since $S_4$ has trivial center, it cannot be nilpotent. Consequently, its lower central series cannot and at $1$ - and it doesn't, as you have shown.

Comment: yes I know that, but the lower central series is central which shouldn't be, because it is central if and only if $S_4$ is nilpotent..

Comment: My problem is how comes that the lower central series is **central** while $S_4$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series we read that :"The lower central series and upper central series (also called the descending central series and ascending central series, respectively), are characteristic series, which, despite the names, are central series if and only if a group is nilpotent."

Comment: Wikipedia has a special definition of "central series", i.e., they define it to terminate. The series for $S_4$ does **not** terminate, so all is OK.

Comment: In this document:http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jbritnel/Teaching/GTnotes4.pdf the author has the same definition of wikipedia and says on page 30 "The lower central series is only a central series when G is nilpotent. (This, unfortunately, is
standard terminology.)" but in page 28 corollary41 he says that $\gamma_i/\gamma_{i+1} $ is central in $G/\gamma_{i+1}$ for all $i$ and then in the next example page 28 he uses the central property to determine $\gamma_3(S_4)$ although $S_4$ is not nilpotent.. I'm confused!!

Comment: It is only a question of definitions. If the definition of (upper, lower) central series includes that it terminates, then certainly $S_4$ does **not** have such a series, since $S_4\ge A_4\ge A_4\ge \cdots$ does not terminate. This series is just called **descending central series**, although it is **not** a central series.